# What are stone tablets for in Noita?

Tags: noita

There's an early game secret which I can pick up, and it is automatically placed in the hotbar. I can throw it, but I can't tell whether it has any effect at all other than being an object with gravity. Is it "just" lore, does it have an immediate effect, or is it something I can use later?

If I missed something in the UI that would be fine to point out. I would encourage keeping spoilers out, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can drop the tablets on the altar located
**<sub>(spoiler alert)</sub>**

> to the right of the cave entrance, on a flying island right above the mountain.

This gives you a small amount of gold (150 IIRC), but also has a small chance of

> summoning strong flying monsters.

---

Also, the tablets can be used as improvised projectiles.

Comment: That's something I wouldn't've tried for a long time. Thanks for the hint! (I'll check the spoilers later :)

Comment: They're really effective short range weapons, and they block projectiles.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the Tabula Smaragdina has 100% chance of spawning monsters, while the others have 100% chance of turning into gold.